# Git pushes entire project even if few files are changed. AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, git-push

I am using Git to push our application to AWS though Elastic Beanstalk. AWS has created the means to do this, although from my understanding it is not exactly a traditional repository. So, for example, I can't `pull` from my Beanstalk project.

I am confused about what is happening during a `push` and why sometimes it is pushing much more data than others. My typical process is as follows

```
//create, edit files
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message here"
[master 7d38f1f] message here
 5 files changed, 27 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)
$ git aws.push
Counting objects: 5131, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4930/4930), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5131/5131), 40.70 MiB | 391.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5131 (delta 1487), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: processing 
To https://exampleLocation
+ 7f9d9dd...7d38f1f HEAD -> master (forced update)
```

Now maybe I'll edit a few files and do another push. This time it will be much smaller/faster

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message2"
[master e2f4412] message2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git aws.push
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 472 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
To https//exampleLocation
7d38f1f..e2f4412  HEAD -> master
```

Tomorrow, when I do my first push, it will might be the big one again...

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337522/how-does-git-push-work) question alludes that only changes are sent, and in the above example you can see that to be true. However, tomorrow when I come in to work my first push will likely be similar to the first one. So somebody is losing track of what has been changed. How can I get it to remember?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was mistaken with my original answer. Here's the updated version.

As we can see from *.git/config*

```
[alias "aws.elasticbeanstalk"]
        remote = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push --remote-url
        push = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push

[alias "aws"]
        push = !git aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
```

*git aws.push* is an invocation of *.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push* Ruby script, which among other code contains the following:

```
commit = opts[:commit] # if commit is specified with --commit
commit = 'HEAD' if commit.nil?

destined_env = opts[:env] || AWS::DevTools.environment()
if !destined_env.nil?
  puts "Pushing to environment: #{destined_env}"
end
`git push -f #{remote} #{commit}:refs/heads/master`
status = $?.exitstatus
exit status
```

In your first log you see the note - *(forced update)*, which you don't see in the second log. Let's look deeper into "forced update".

From [git-push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) manual:

> -f
>   --force
>   Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag
>   disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose
>   commits; use it with care.

Remote ref might not be an ancestor in at least two cases:

- when it is the ref itself, when attempting to push the same commit
- when someone else updated the remote repository and your commit have to overwrite their changes

I believe that one of those cases is yours.

Or it might be a bug in AWS tools. Previously there was [another issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=336101), with remote repository not being updated after the changes were made locally. Maybe that was the fix - to use force with push.

I'm going to dig deeper into the issue, and will update the answer once I have more information.

Comment: I understand that ELB is NOT a repository. And I understand everything else you're saying. My question though, is why are some pushes huge and others small? And how can I get them all to stay small? Something must be keeping track of changes. What is doing this? and how can I keep it awake and functioning?

Comment: @TimSum Updated the answer with detailed information. There are still open questions.