# git push - https/ssh protocol

Tags: github, networking, ssh, https, gitlab

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337533/3317808) does not have valid link

For both GitHub & GitLab, we only have https access through browser. Installing Git in local laptop does not help us run `git add remote https://github.com/abc/xyz.git`
 or `git fetch --all`

---

1) How does git client(`git push` or `git fetch --all`) work with GitLab or GitHub remote repo? Is it through `https` or `ssh`?

2) What ports need to be enabled on GitHub remote repo(server)?
to run such commands

Comment: The corrected link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

Comment: *we only have https access through browser* Proxy?

Comment: *Installing Git in local laptop does not help* What's the problem?

Comment: @phd gitlab is running on public cloud foundry on azure cloud which can be connected thru bastion server(jumpbox), by the admin of that setup. Jenkins can access gitlab because they are behind bastion server.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Gitlab, you can work by HTTP / HTTPS / SSH. I do not remember if Github supports also HTTP(S) or has been dropped the support. On Github, you can use HTTPS for PULL, but I didn't remember if you can use also for PUSH.

The ports will depend on the server configuration and protocol. But if the configuration are standard, ports will be 443 for HTTPS or 22 for SSH.

Comment: Github perfectly supports HTTPS.